# Prove that the convergence of $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ implies $\lim_{n→∞} b_n = 1$

Tags: infinite-product

So I am stuck on this question and am unsure how to solve it, would be appreciated if someone could help me out, thanks! :)

**Question**

Consider a sequence $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of non-zero real numbers. By definition, the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges if the sequence $(p_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, where

$p_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n}b_k$

converges to some non-zero number. Prove that the convergence of $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=1$

Comment: Is it really true? What if $b_n=\frac1n$?

Comment: @Sayan: That is not a convergent product. Diverges to $0$.

Answer (score 7):

Hint:

$$b_n = \frac{\prod_{k=1}^nb_k}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}b_k}$$

Comment: Yes . That is why OP specified the product converges to a non-zero number

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but would you be able to clarify, I'm unsure how this can be utilised, thanks

Comment: @JamesBlair Since the product converges, say to $L$, the limit of the ratio equals the ratio of the limits ... which is $L/L=1$.

Comment: @JamesBlair: If $P_n \to P \neq 0$ then $b_n = P_n/P_{n-1} \to P/P = 1$

Comment: (+1) In view of the (new) other answer and its comments, it would perhaps be useful (for students) to insert in yours either a link to an epsilon-proof for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n}$ (we could create such a post if, as it seems, none is available), or a short such proof directly appended here.

Comment: (follow up) In case nothing happens, I leave here a sketch: for any $y≠0$ and $x$ in $\Bbb C$ (or more generally, [for @azimut](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4834374/timeline#comment_10293267), in any [topological field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_ring)) and any $ϵ′>0$, let
$$0<\epsilon<|y|\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon'|y|}{|x|+|y|+\epsilon'|y|}\right).$$
Then,
$$|u-x|,|v-y|\le\epsilon\implies\left|\frac uv-\frac xy\right|<\epsilon'.$$

Answer (score 1):

As comments are suddenly appearing, I thought I'd take a moment to fix the original, flawed answer. Clearly, RRL's answer is perfectly sufficient and quite straight-forward. However, it's sometimes a nice exercise to use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition for limits, so I'll do that rather than delete the answer altogether.

---

Suppose that $p_n \to p$. Then $p_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Fix $\epsilon' > 0$, and choose $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\epsilon < \min \left\{\frac{|p|}2, K\right\}$, where $K := \min\left\{\left\vert p - \frac{\vert p \vert}2\right\vert, \ \left\vert p + \frac{\vert p \vert}2\right\vert\right\}$. Suppose that $N \in \mathbb{N}$ is such that $n, m \ge \mathbb{N}$ implies $\vert p_n - p_m \vert < \epsilon$. In particular, taking $m \to \infty$, we see that $|p_n - p| < \epsilon$, which can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
p - \frac{|p|}2 < p - \epsilon < \ & p_n < p + \epsilon < p + \frac{|p|}2 \\
K < |p_n| < \max&\left\{\left\vert p - \frac{\vert p \vert}2\right\vert, \ \left\vert p + \frac{\vert p \vert}2\right\vert\right\}.
\end{align*}

Finally, observing that $p_{n+1} - p_n = p_n(a_{n+1} - 1),$ we see that
\begin{align*}
|a_{n+1} - 1| = \frac{|p_{n+1} - p_n|}{|p_n|} < \frac{\epsilon}{K} < \epsilon'
\end{align*}
From which it follows that $a_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I have doubts about this proof at the point "Remember $\epsilon$ can be any number $ > 0$". Yes, $\epsilon$ can be any real number $> 0$, but it must be a fixed value from the beginning. In your proof, you start with some $\epsilon'$. Then $N$ depends on $\epsilon'$, and then you readjust $\epsilon'$ to an $\epsilon$ depending on $n \geq N$. I have the feeling that this is a circular argument.

Comment: I am the 2nd downvoter. I agree with @azimut. This proof could be fixed (but should better be deleted, imo) by using some positive $\alpha$ such that $\forall n$ large enough, $|a_{n-1}|>\alpha$.

Comment: @azimut This is quite an old post, but you're correct that the proof was fairly erroneous. For the sake of offering an alternative proof to the (should have been) accepted answer by RRL, I've reworked my own.

Comment: @AnneBauval I've updated the original answer to provide a correct proof using an epsilon-delta argument. I don't feel it's worth deleting at this point, as having students practice such a methodology is useful (even when applying limit properties is much easier). I was a university student myself at the time of the original post, and the errors I made were precisely those that I see students making now, for which I leave the original answer instead of writing a new one—to preserve the edit history.

Comment: @infinitylord many thanks for coming back to this answer and revising it. I completely agree that it is good to have an alternative approach, and there is no reason for deletion as long as it can be fixed. I will read the answer and change my -1 vote to +1 as appropriate.

Comment: @infinitylord Your old approach was looking at the differences $p_m - p_n$ of partial products, which is an interesting alternative to the answer of RRL. But now you switched to quotients $p_m / p_n$, which is basically the same as what RRL did. Hence, it is now basically the same answer...

Comment: Moreover, it is uselessly complicated and only applies to real sequences. In order to get directly
$$|p-u|,|p-v|\le\epsilon\implies\frac{|v-u|}{|u|}<\epsilon',$$
the most natural (hence most educational) choice is:
$$0<\frac{2\epsilon}{|p|-\epsilon}<\epsilon',$$
i.e.
$$\epsilon<|p|\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon'}{2+\epsilon'}\right).$$ Still more educational would be, imo, to delete this answer and to add in @RRL's answer a link to an epsilon-proof for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n}$ (we could create such a post if none is available).

Comment: @azimut I've changed the relevant line to use the differences instead, but it is the exact same observation: $a_n = p_n / p_{n-1}$ and $p_{n} - p_{n-1} = p_{n-1}(a_{n} - 1)$, the latter which I used in the original answer, the former in the prior update. Moreover, RRL's answer was clearly heading towards using the "limit of quotients is the quotient of their limits (provided the denominator is non-zero)" result, as mentioned in the comments. I don't believe that providing an epsilon-delta proof that happens to use the same initial observation makes them the same answer.

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't personally find your approach more natural, just more concise. But we will have to agree to disagree on that matter, and what is more educational. Should the answer obtain the necessary votes to be deleted, then of course I will accept it, but I do personally believe there is reason to keep it.

Comment: @infinitylord Many thanks for the clarification. While I think that the the bounds can be done a bit nicer (see the comment of Anne Bauval), I agree that the approach works and corresponds to looking at the difference of the partial products. My interpretation is that you resolved the circular dependency "$N$ depends on $\epsilon$, $\epsilon$ depends on $N$" by bringing the limit $p$ into the game.

Comment: @infinitylord BTW, the reason for the sudden comments on your old answer is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4834374/61691