# $\epsilon$-proof for convergent infinite product

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, alternative-proof, cauchy-sequences, infinite-product

**Setting**

There is the following statement about infinite products:

> If $\prod_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is convergent (which by convention means that the limit is not zero), then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 1$.

The common proof is to apply $\ln$ to transform the partial products into partial sums, and then to use the corresponding statement about convergent infinite series (stating that summands form a zero sequence).

**Question**

I'm looking for an elementary $\epsilon$-proof, without the usage of $\ln$. Also, I would like to avoid inversion of the elements $a_i$.

**What I have tried**

So far, I have:
If $\prod_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is convergent, then the sequence of partial products
$$p_n = a_0\cdot a_1 \cdots a_n$$
is a Cauchy sequence. Hence for $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$,
$$
\epsilon > \lvert p_{n+1} - p_n\rvert = \lvert a_1\rvert\cdot \ldots \cdot \lvert a_n\rvert \cdot \lvert a_{n+1} - 1\rvert.
$$
So
$$\lvert a_{n+1} - 1\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{\lvert a_1\rvert\cdot \ldots \cdot \lvert a_n\rvert}.$$

Now the problem is that I need to bound the product $\lvert a_1\rvert\cdot \ldots \cdot \lvert a_n\rvert$ from below, but I don't see a clear way how to do it.

**Addition**

Anne Bauval has brought up [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2303633/61691). Initially, there has been a flaw in that answer, but now that it is fixed I agree that it answers my question.

Comment: $p_n$ and $p_{n-1}$ converge to the same nonzero value, right? What's the limit of $p_n/p_{n-1}$?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Thank you, your comment is helpful for the question as I stated it. But actually, I would like to avoid inversion, too. (I plan to apply the proof to certain ring situations...)

Comment: Ah, that's different then. You should state precisely your problem in the question, otherwise it will be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: If I state exactly what I aim at, noone will pay attention :) So I decided to ask the question in the classical setting, not realizing that it is not only the ln, but also the inversion which I want to avoid. I added a clarification to the question.

Comment: @AnneBauval Many thanks for the pointer. Answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2303633/61691 looks like what I am looking for. But I think there is a flaw in the reasoning, I've added a comment there. So please leave this question open.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps because I do not know much about infinite products. But if you cannot bound the $|p_n|$ from below, i.e., for any $\delta > 0$ there's a $n$ with $0 < |p_n| < \delta$, can't you inductively construct a subsequence converging to 0, proving that $p_n \to 0$, which by assumption we rule out?

Comment: The other answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2303597 is (rightly, imo) much more upvoted, and sufficient for your purpose. You should work separately (or better, find a link on this site) for an epsilon-proof of the fact that if $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y\ne0$ then $x_n/y_n\to x/y$. For all these reasons, I maintain my vote to close the present post as a duplicate. The discussion about the old answer you are doubting should continue [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2303633), not here.

Comment: @AnneBauval I would like to avoid division by the elements $a_n$ (which I have specified in an update to my question). The "much more upvoted" answer therefore is not an applicable. The approach in the other answer looked promising, but it was flawed and the revision now also switched to quotients.

Comment: I saw you now "would like to...", but you didn't give any convincing motivation for such a contrived approach.

Comment: @AnneBauval Come on, why all the negative vibrations? I have indicated my motivation in a comment above, but o.k., you push me to give the full story. I would like to have the corresponding statement in the ring $R[[X]]$ of formal power series over a domain $R$, which is a complete metric space in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series

Comment: I formulated the question in the way I did because (a) I thought that ln-free would be enough (not being aware of the natural $p_{n+1}/p_n$ proof which made me add the division-free condition later) and (b) because I feared that less people would read the question when laying it out in that uncommon setting.

Comment: The related answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2303633/61691 has been fixed and thus this question can be closed as a duplicate.